# Not able Unlock Window Vm which is configured inside the ubuntu server QEMU/KVM

Tags: window, virtual-machine, ubuntu-16.04

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRGSX.jpg)

Window server VM is configured on Ubuntu server 16.04.7 inside the Virtual Machine Manager.

But the problem as i have to open Windows server from VM it shows locked screen, and the keyboard key is not processing i tried Ctrl + Alt + Delete but no response.

The keyboard key is completely off, nothing is going to process, its is a serious issue for me.

tried with Ctrl + Alt + ESC, tried with all possbile keys and combination of keys but No lock and screen is not processing.

even i tried using Send keys from top of the VM no thing is going to work.

I rebooted the ubuntu Server, restarted Windows VM but nothing happened.

I want to unlock the VM.

Comment: did you look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293497/help-setting-up-a-windows-vm-with-qemu-kvm